# How to separate names and numbers given in a text file into different list in Python

Tags: python, string, file, text, split

I am required to **calculate their average scores ignoring the minimum and the maximum scores.** But I don't know how to separate the given text file into two different list. **Is it correct to separate them into two different list like names and scores first?**

Given in text file:

Alice 8 10 8 0 10

Brown 5 7 2 3 6

Rick 9 10 1 9 3

Mark 1 10 0 2 9

Andrew 1 5 10 10 9

Maria 5 5 5 5 5

Sean 0 10 0 0 0

Alan 10 10 10 10 10

Michael 0 0 0 0 0

Jenny 1 2 3 4 5

*PS: I'm new to programming.*

Comment: So new to programming that you can't write anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since your new and your just looking for the approach you should take then i will answer, but you really should at-least try in some way to tackle any coding part before posting the question so people here can offer advice on how to improve what you have already done.

### **Read the file**

Firstly you want to read in your file and find a way to check each lines content:

```
f = open('myfile.txt')
for line in iter(f):
    print line
f.close()
```

Since each line contains a string with varying types of content, you will want to access that.

### **Split line into array**

Split your current line by the space

```
splitLine = line.split(" ")
#or 
import re
splitLine = re.split('\s+', line)
```

Each line will now be an array of your string parts split by a space, like this :

> > > "many   fancy word \nhello    \thi".split()
> > >       ['many', 'fancy', 'word', 'hello', 'hi']

Each array for your particular format should have 6 elements which you should be able to access:

**All content**

```
for row in splitLine:
    print(row)
```

**One element**

```
print("Element:", splitLine[0])
```

Anyway hope this helps you get started in solving your question and good luck on your project.